# Script to Airdrop ERC-20 token

Tags: airdrop

I've created a token on testnet out of curiosity. Token was created I'm able to transfer token to other testnet wallet I created.

I'm interest to run an airdrop to all of this testnet wallet but I'm struggled to find an easy guide on how to do that. (I'm not from programming based though)

My logic behind an airdrop should consist of :

1. Recipient address and number of token they entitled to (unsure in what format this data should compile in)
2. The main wallet that hold all the token (rather than a contract)
3. A script that execute the airdrop by matching the "amount of token recipient entitled to" and "their wallet address"
4. A mass send script to perform the airdrop.

Anyone can assist on this please? Although I'm not profiting from it but still, I find it interesting if I'm able to do the whole "basic" thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use Dapple Airdrops which facilitates token distributions in batches of at least 150 addresses at a time! Here is the URL: https://www.dappleairdrops.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be useful to use open-source https://github.com/bulktokensending/bulktokensending Deployed version is here http://bulktokensending.online
You can generate ETH addresses and do the mass transfers depends on your own selected chunk size.